# Print Envelope using Only Office and HP Printer

Tags: printing, hp

How to Print a #10 Envelope using Only Office and HP OfficeJet Pro 8740 Printer ?

I am using Ubuntu 20.04, and I have onlyoffice-desktopeditors 6.1.0-90 installed.

I have successfully setup the HP 8740 printer using cups.
I can print letter sized and legal sized pages and I can scan.

I need to print a #10 Envelope.

These are the steps I've taken, but the envelope comes out empty.

Only Office:

1. Selected page size: Envelope #10 (10.48 cm x 24.13 cm)
2. Set orientation: Landscape
3. Typed address information

HP 8740:

1. Removed Letter sized paper from tray #1.
2. Inserted #10 envelope in tray #1, face down per diagram
3. Adjusted guides so envelope fits
4. Changed paper size to #10 envelope on the printer menu

Ubuntu's Printers App:

1. Verified HP 8740 is the default printer
2. In Printer Options | General | Media Type, selected "Envelope #10"
3. In Printer Options | Paper/Quality | Paper Source, selected "Tray 1"

Only Office:

1. Click the print Icon
2. Ensure Printer name is the HP 8740 printer.
3. Click Print button.

On hunch, I placed a US Letter sized paper in the tray, but left all settings as shown above.
The address information did print, but on the left, long edge of the Letter sized paper.

When I place the envelope into the tray, it is centered in the tray. The guides keep the envelope in place, so it can not be shifted to the left edge of the tray.

The printer seems to be trying to print outsize the physical size of the envelope.

Is there something I need to do in Only Office, in the Printer Settings in Ubuntu, or on the printer in order to make this work?

EDIT:
Regardless of what paper size I select in Only Office, the printer always gives the following error. So, even though I select "Envelope #10" in Only Office, and the printer tray actually has a #10 Envelope, the job that the printer receives always seems to be sent as A4 size job. I winder if CUPS or Only Office incorrectly sends the page size every time? (I've been able to print legal size documents in the past).

> The paper size detected by the printer in Tray 1 does not march the paper size selected (A4 (210x297 mm)) for the print job.
>
> Make sure the paper size is correct to continue the job.
>
> Touch X to cancel the print job.

Comment: I don't have LibreOffice installed on my system, and don't want to install all the LibreOffice packages just for this one print job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution (work-around) is to save the document as a PDF and print it from a different application.

Only Office seems to always use A4 size for all print jobs, ignoring the selected paper size. Even selecting "Print to File (PDF)" from Only Office's print dialog will generate a PDF document that has A4 size.

However, the "Save as" feature produces PDFs of the desired paper size.

**HP OfficeJet Pro 8740 (or other printer):**

1. Remove original (Letter) size paper from Tray #1
2. Insert a #10 envelope in Tray #1 (face down with the flap to the left for HP 8740)
3. Adjust the paper guides to fit the envelope
4. Change the paper size to "#10 Envelope" in the printer's menu

**Only Office:**

1. Set page size: "Envelope #10 (10.48 cm x 24.13 cm)"
2. Set orientation: "Landscape"
3. Set Margins: "Narrow"
4. Type the address information in the document
5. **Do **not** select the "Print" option.**
6. Select "File" from the menu bar
7. Select "Save As"
8. Enter a file name
9. From the drop down at the bottom of the Save dialog, select "PDF File"
10. Click the "Save" button

**Open the new PDF file in Document Viewer:**

1. Click the menu (hamburger) in the header bar
2. Click the printer icon
3. On the "General" tab, select your printer
4. On the "Page Setup" tab, set Paper size: "#10 Envelope"
5. Keep Orientation: "Portrait" (9.50 inch x 4.13 inch)
6. Click the "Print" button in the header bar

Note: I have created the following bug report: [Print feature ignores paper size, always produces A4 size printouts](https://github.com/ONLYOFFICE/DesktopEditors/issues/560). Please go to the bug report and mark yourself as impacted, if you experience this issue.